# What is the difference between file:/, file://, file:///

Tags: url

Today I saw in a Java application several different approaches to load a file.

- file:/
- file://
- file:///

What is the difference of these three URL beginnings and what is the preferred way of using them?

Thanks a lot
Stefan

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme

Comment: according to the wiki above, "file:/path" is valid while "file://path" is not. This seems to contradict the answers below.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

- `file:/` is invalid as far as I know
- `file://` is the prefix for the file protocol
- `file:///` is the prefix for the file protocol, plus a leading `/` pointing to the root directory of the current drive (On Windows) or the overall root directory (On Linux / Unix).

Comment: +1 On windows remote drives, the `file://` protocol prefix leads to even four slashes: `file:////other/mydir/myfile.txt` for a file `\\other\mydir\myfile.txt` (see http://mindprod.com/jgloss/uri.html).

Comment: @chris_li ahahahaha, hadn't thought of that scenario! That looks just *crazy*. Great addition.

Comment: Oddly enough, the Windows command prompt and folder address bars seem to allow any number of slashes except 5 or 6 when a drive letter is used. So these all work: `file:c:/test.txt`, `file:/c:/test.txt`, `file://////////c:/test.txt`; but this doesn't: `file://///c:/test.txt`. The rules are stricter when a host name or IP is used, e.g. `file://127.0.0.1/c$/test.txt`. Only 2,4,5 or 6 slashes are allowed in this case. 'Course, the rules may be completely different in a different context, such as a Java app.

Comment: On Linux the `nautilus` file manager seems to accept `file:/` (with a single slash) when entered directly into the address bar such as `file:/usr/`. So this may be invalid as per the specification, but some implementations accept it.

Comment: this "file:// is the prefix for the file protocol" is plainly wrong. This  "file:" is protocol and schema designator.  After it, sign `//` designates two things: 1) hierarchical, path alike, addressing is used and 2) the path after it is root relative.

Additional `/` in `file:///` is redundant.

Answer (score 6):

file:/ is invalid, and shouldn't work
file:/// is a shorthand for: file://localhost/
file:// is the recommended method