# Java URL("file://") doesn't work on Windows XP

Tags: java, file, url, path, windows-xp

For some reason the following code doesn't work on Windows XP.

```
new URL("file://" + tempfile.getAbsolutePath());
```

I'm using Java 1.6.

```
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_31-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.6-b01, mixed mode, sharing)
```

However, the same code just works fine in OS X (Lion) and Java 1.6

```
java version "1.6.0_29"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_29-b11-402-11M3527)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.4-b02-402, mixed mode)
```

Linux (Linux 2.6.32-38-generic #83-Ubuntu x86_64 GNU/Linux) with Java 1.6

```
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616795/what-is-the-difference-between-file-file-file) the above code should work.

Comment: From what I remember,  you may need to use a file:/// notation on windows.  Try it and see if it works.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What is the problem with `File.toURI().toURL()`? Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: it can't be used in properties / yaml files

Answer (score 21):

On the localhost the URL looks like:

```
file:///Folder
```

Very important the third slash...

On Windows the Folder looks like:

```
file:///C:/path/
```

Answer (score 7):

The following code should avoid all the hassles

```
new File(tempfile.getAbsolutePath()).toURI().toURL()
```