# Create link out of string to folder

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have custom control on which I can print only strings, but I need to create link to folder on local machine out of that string so it should look like this:

[image]

I tried entering:

```
$"Folder: <href = '{OutputInfo.FolderPath}'>{OutputInfo.FolderPath}</href>"
```

but for some reason sometimes it works, sometime it doesn't and I don't understand why is so. When it doesn't work it prints like this:

[image]

Can anyone propose any solution to this?

EDIT:

I want to be able to click on link and that action should open folder in windows

EDIT2:

Code was missing > so I added it

Comment: What is your project / framework / application?

Comment: c# .net winforms

Comment: is it because you are missing the '>' of href tag in this $"Folder: <href = '{OutputInfo.FolderPath}' {OutputInfo.FolderPath}</href>"?

Comment: Assuming that this is html, the correct syntax would be `$"Folder: <a href='file://{OutputInfo.FolderPath}'>{OutputInfo.FolderPath}</a>"` (i.e. `a` instead of of `href`, `file://` protocol)

Comment: @StephanBauer Doesn't the file:/// protocol have three slashes?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Only if you want to point to the root directory, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3616814/314334)

Comment: @KarthikGanesan I missed that in code, sorry. It is there, I edited post

Comment: @StephanBauer it doesn't work that way too, it prints out whole thing as a string. Three slashes doesn't help ether

Comment: Well then it seems that your control does not support html but only text

Comment: Can you show the output when it works?

Comment: @StephanBauer Hmmm... that seems to contradict the information in the Wikipedia article [file URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) as the OP is showing the use of the drive letter.

Comment: @AndrewMorton ah ok I wasn't aware of that

Comment: @KarthikGanesan Output when it works is up in the post. It prints it out as hyperlink and everything works fine

Answer (score 1):

How about a `LinkLabel`?
MS Doc about `LinkLabel` [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.linklabel?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        linkLabel1.Links.Add(0, linkLabel1.Text.Length, @"D:\temp");
        linkLabel1.Text = @"D:\temp";
    }

    private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start((string)e.Link.LinkData);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's legacy code and this is custom control. I can't add up more controls and I can only print strings. It crossed my mind, but I can't implement it unfortunately