# NoSuchFileException - first slash is removed

Tags: java, spring-batch

The following code is working locally on my dev env Windows machine but not on the Unix machine.

```
 @Override
public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {

      ResourcePatternResolver patternResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
      try {
        activationResources = patternResolver.getResources("file:/opt/racer-batch-app/*.csv");
    } catch (IOException e) {
```

It looks like the first slash is removed and therefore the file is not found.

```
nested exception is java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: opt/racer-batch-app/Activatio.csv
```

Any idea what am I missing?

Thank you

Comment: I would check the filepath. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3616814/11153525

Comment: 'Full' file protocol starts `file:///`. Try starting like that

Comment: Thank you all. Appreciate the help. The root cause was in other function.